# Context.Response.End() and Thread was being aborted

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to close the response using `Context.Response.End` but receive error `"Thread was being aborted"`.

How do I correctly close the response without triggering an exception?

```
try {
   Context.Response.Clear();
   Context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"; 
   //Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
   JsonObjectCollection collection = new JsonObjectCollection();
   collection.Add(new JsonNumericValue("resultcode", 1));
   collection.Add(new JsonStringValue("sourceurl", exchangeData.cUrl));
   collection.Add(new JsonStringValue("filename", fileName));
   collection.Add(new JsonStringValue("filesize", fileSize));
   collection.Add(new JsonStringValue("fileurl", Common.GetPDFURL + outputFileName));
   JsonUtility.GenerateIndentedJsonText = true;
   Context.Response.Write(collection);
  try {
     Context.Response.End();
  } catch (ThreadAbortException exc) {
     // This should be first catch block i.e. before generic Exception
     // This Catch block is to absorb exception thrown by Response.End
  }
} catch (Exception err) {

}
```

Solved by myself, the code should look like

```
try {
  Context.Response.End();
} catch (ThreadAbortException err) {

}
catch (Exception err) {
}
```

Comment: do you have the respose.end inside a try catch block?

Comment: I have added my code. Yes I have added Context.Response.End(); inside Try/catch  block and as you see there is main Try/catch block which is also catch error "Thread was being aborted".

Comment: Solved by myself, the code should look like

try 
{
}
        catch (ThreadAbortException err)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
        }

Answer (score 27):

Is there a specific reason you aren't using `context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instead?

This method will short circuit the ASP.NET pipeline (except for the EndRequest event) without throwing the `ThreadAbortException` so you won't need the extra `try`/`catch` block, and you will also experience better performance.

Comment: I've just tried this (a little late to the party). It didn't seem to work properly: certainly it didn't throw the exception Response.End() threw, but it did result in the contents of the .aspx page being appended to what I'd already writen to the Response.OutputStream.  One option might be to have no content in the .aspx file but I've used that to have the content to display for errors.

Answer (score 10):

Try **response.OutputStream.Close();** instead of **response.End();**
It will help!

Answer (score 2):

Error: Thread was being aborted. at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()

This error occurs mainly If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer

Cause: The Response.End method ends the page execution and shifts the execution to the Application_EndRequest event in the application’s event pipeline. The line of code that follows Response.End is not executed.

This problem occurs in the Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer methods because both methods call Response.End internally.

Resolution/Solution:

You can use a try-catch statement to catch this exception

or

For Response.End, call the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the Application_EndRequest event. For Response.Redirect, use an overload, Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse) that passes false for the endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End. For example: ex: Response.Redirect (“nextpage.aspx”, false); If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed. For Server.Transfer, use the Server.Execute method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this solution :

1. Don't use response.End();
2. Declare this global var : bool isFileDownLoad;
3. Just after your (response.Write(sw.ToString());) set ==>  isFileDownLoad = true;
4. Override your Render  like :

   /// 
   /// AEG : Very important to handle the thread aborted exception
   /// 
   /// 
   override protected void Render(HtmlTextWriter w)
   {
       if (!isFileDownLoad) base.Render(w);
   }

Answer (score 0):

Or you can place the **context.Response.End() inside a finally bloc**. That way you won't have to care about undesired ThreadAbortException, nor ignore real ThreadAbortException (which is bad). You also won't ignore pipeline stages.

```
try
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    if (NotAuthorized())
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return;
    }

    context.Response.Write(MakeJsonStuff());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogException(ex);

    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    context.Response.Write(MakeJsonError(ex));
}
finally
{
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to handle `Thread was being aborted` exception,

```
try
{
   //Write HTTP output
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Data);
}  
catch (Exception exc) {}
finally {
   try 
    {
      //stop processing the script and return the current result
      HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
     } 
   catch (Exception ex) {} 
   finally {
        //Sends the response buffer
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        // Prevents any other content from being sent to the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
        //Directs the thread to finish, bypassing additional processing
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        //Suspends the current thread
        Thread.Sleep(1);
     }
   }
```

if you use the following the following code instead of `HttpContext.Current.Response.End()` , you will get `Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent` exception.

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = True;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Another Fix which I found is `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();`

```
   try 
 {
    //Write HTTP output
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Data);
  } catch (Exception exc) {} 
  finally {
    try {
     //Notifies a host that execution is about to enter a region of code in which the effects of a thread abort or unhandled exception might jeopardize other tasks in the application domain.
     Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
         } catch (Exception ex) {} 
    finally {
    //Sends the response buffer
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    // Prevents any other content from being sent to the browser
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
    //Directs the thread to finish, bypassing additional processing
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
         }
   }
```

Hope it helps