# ASP.NET file download from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

After a user clicks a button, I want a file to be downloaded. I've tried the following which seems to work, but not without throwing an exception (ThreadAbort) which is not acceptable.

```
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
    response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("FileDownload.csv"));
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
```

Comment: You can check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378204/context-response-end-and-thread-was-being-aborted

Comment: `response.End()` is causing the `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: This is a bug in the .NET framework and has been reported in numerous SO questions. Catch the ThreadAbort and be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a file download in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650/how-to-implement-a-file-download-in-asp-net)

Comment: The issue is that I need several files to be downloaded. When an exception is thrown, it interrupts the download of the of the following files, even if the exception is caught.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use an HTTP Handler (.ashx) to download a file, like this:

DownloadFile.ashx:

```
public class DownloadFile : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {   
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                           "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("FileDownload.csv"));
        response.Flush();    
        response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call the HTTP Handler from the button click event handler, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download File" 
            OnClick="btnDownload_Click"/>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("PathToHttpHandler/DownloadFile.ashx");
}
```

---

**Passing a parameter to the HTTP Handler:**

You can simply append a query string variable to the `Response.Redirect()`, like this:

```
Response.Redirect("PathToHttpHandler/DownloadFile.ashx?yourVariable=yourValue");
```

Then in the actual handler code you can use the `Request` object in the `HttpContext` to grab the query string variable value, like this:

```
System.Web.HttpRequest request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
string yourVariableValue = request.QueryString["yourVariable"];

// Use the yourVariableValue here
```

**Note** - it is common to pass a filename as a query string parameter to suggest to the user what the file actually is, in which case they can override that name value with Save As...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to pass folder location as parameter, so passing it in query won't be the good idea. Is there any other way, we can pass values?

Comment: @KarlAnderson is it possible to use this via $.ajax method? I have a single page application where I need to use this approaching of downloading file via asp.net handler. Can you help?

Comment: Why the ";" after fileName. 
 response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                           "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");

Comment: Any difference having this on .aspx  than .ashx. I have an exemple that downloads using.aspx and a standalone page, but doesn't works when wrapping the site on another

Comment: I am getting an error in `Server.MapPath()` : `Server` in the event handler

Comment: @Si8 try making it context.Server.

Answer (score 13):

Try this set of code to download a CSV file from the server.

```
byte[] Content= File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath); //missing ;
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".csv");
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.OutputStream.Write(Content, 0, Content.Length);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 4):

Making changes as below and redeploying on server content type as

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

This worked for me.

```
Response.Clear(); 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name); 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString()); 
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName); 
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 3):

None of these worked for me on ASP.NET 6.0 MVC Razor

Example within a controller class add this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
/// <summary>
/// Creates a download file stream for the user.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IActionResult Download([FromQuery] string fileName)
{
    var filePath = "[...path to file...]";

    var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    return File(fs, "application/[... content type...]", fileName);
}
}
```

Example within the view .cshtml file:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Download", "Home", new { fileName = quote.fileName })">Download File</a>
```

Comment: For unknown file types use ```"application/force-download"``` in contentType. thanks for answer

Answer (score 2):

Further to Karl Anderson solution, you could put your parameters into session information and then clear them after `response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath( Session(currentSessionItemName)));`.

See MSDN page *[HttpSessionState.Add Method (String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.add(v=vs.110).aspx)* for more information on sessions.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void DescargarArchivo(string strRuta, string strFile)
{
    FileInfo ObjArchivo = new System.IO.FileInfo(strRuta);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", ObjArchivo.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.WriteFile(ObjArchivo.FullName);
    Response.End();


}
```

Comment: if you use web form the button must have a trigger to postback

Comment: WriteFile vs TransmitFile?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for downloading a file from the server:

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FileName = "Durgesh.jpg"; // It's a file name displayed on downloaded file on client side.

            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
            response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/File/001.jpg"));
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        }
```