# Encrypting src attribute of iframe control

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe, encryption, browser

I am using iframe to load a pdf file from a temporary location , which looks as shown below

```
<iframe id="myPDF" width="100%" height="100%" src="Config\Temp\tmp_report_0.pdf"></iframe>
```

this will load up a pdf file to browser window, inside the iframe.
My question is how can i hide this 'src' value from being visible to user when they right click and select 'view source' from browser.

The intention is here to enrcypt/hide the 'src' value from users.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **generic handler** to hide the actually file from location.

Inside your handler you serve the file base on a url parameter. Here is a basic example:

```
 <iframe id="myPDF" width="100%" height="100%" src="OpenReport.ashx?ReportId=2129938212"></iframe>
```

Now you can/must encrypt also the url parameter to avoid anyone download all your reports.

An example of handler to download the file : [ASP.NET file download from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server/18477989#18477989)

From that you remove all the line that contains the `attachment; filename=` so the file will be load on the inside of the iframe. Of course you can find many other examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SECURITY property.

```
<IFRAME ID="myPDF"
        SECURITY="restricted"  
        WIDTH="100%"
        HEIGHT="100%" 
        SRC="Config\Temp\tmp_report_0.pdf" />
```

Or check this link
[Hide SRC tag](http://forums.asp.net/t/1604127.aspx?Hide%20src%20of%20IFRAME%20in%20ASP%20NET%20Page)

Comment: this does not hide from viewing the src

Answer (score 0):

Is your PDF static or dynamic?
If dynamic then would suggest to make httphandler which generates pdf and return url. Then add src attribute/modify src attribute using JavaScript. also, handler can be called using Javascript. Still this will not be hidden if user uses developer toolbar of browser to inspect element.

Comment: Thats what i said, you can not hide that. You can encapsulate that.