# c# - HttpResponse file download not working - "file couldn't be downloaded"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to allow a user to download a file using the following server-side C# code:

```
public static HttpResponse ExportDataToUser(string settings)
        {
            string filename = "CurrentSettings.txt";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(new StringBuilder(settings));
            //Open a memory stream that you can use to write back to the response
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
            MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.ASCII);
            //Write the stream back to the response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            //sr.Close();
            //sr.Dispose();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
            return HttpContext.Current.Response;
        }
```

When the method reaches the `Flush` line, this download bar at the bottom of the screen appears but when I click `Open`, the I am prompted that the "file couldn't be downloaded." The client side call that invokes this method has `dataType: "text/plain"`. Does anyone have an idea why the download is failing?

Comment: you can use httphandler check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server