# C# open file from physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net

sorry for asking a silly question it seems to be,
I am new to programming and trying to write a asp .net web application.

One part of the application had generated and saved some document 
(like pdf, excel, words, gif, jpg, etc.) to a physical path in server side,

User can choose to download the file by clicking a button

is there something like "window.open(url)" that can raise a file download dialog box with known document type in javascript / c#?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: [This similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult) might be of help!

Comment: Could [this][1] link be of use? Looks like they are doing a similar thing.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server