# why Response.End Not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, httpresponse

May be it is a Duplicate question. But my case is something different.  I have a page to download the text file. In the page first i decrypt the text file into `string plainText`. then write that string into a file and upload to a folder named as Decrypted Files. The download that decrypted file and delete previously saved file.

here is my code for download

```
                //Write the decrypted text to folder in the server.
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Decrypted Files/" + FileName), plainText);

                //Code for Download
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='" + FileName + "'");
                Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/Decrypted Files/" + FileName));

                //Delete File from the folder
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Decrypted Files/" + FileName)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete((Server.MapPath("~/Decrypted Files/" + FileName)));
                }

                Response.End();
```

But The code execution not continue from `Response.End();` and the .aspx page not finishing its loading. What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Why not run the project and enable Exception settings/set debug points? The problem can be from other lines instead of Response.End. See this answer too - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18477989/2010289

Comment: "The code execution not continue from Response.End()" -  Can you please clarify what this sentence mean? Obviously you know that `Response.End` throws ThreadAbortException, so you are not expecting code *after* that line to execute... so what code you are talking about?

Comment: Try Response.TransmitFile instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i got what is wrong with my code. Before ending I deleted the file. So i changed the code as follows and everything working fine.

```
                //Write the decrypted text to folder in the server.
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Decrypted Files/" + FileName), plainText);

                //Code for Download
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='" + FileName + "'");
                Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/Decrypted Files/" + FileName));
                Response.Flush();

                //Delete File from the folder
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Decrypted Files/" + FileName)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete((Server.MapPath("~/Decrypted Files/" + FileName)));
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score -1):

put that button (which you are using to export) in update panel

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).