# how to open new browser window from asp.net handler file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code below works fine in debug from visual studio but when I publish it to IIS server doesn't work. Just nothing happens. I'm guessing some security issues. Question is if there are any alternatives for System.Diagnostics.Process.Start to open an url in new window or tab?  Or how to make Process.Strat work in IIS?
thanks

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["path"] == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string path = Context.Server.UrlDecode(Context.Request.QueryString["path"]);

        var item = DataServer.GetItem(path);
        if (item == null) return;

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(item["sourcePath"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code.  You can't do that.

Comment: you don't understand the question and problem. This code works in debug.

Comment: @ZuluZ It works in debug because when debugging, your server and client is the same machine.

Comment: Exactly.  You need to understand the difference between the client and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is being opened at server side and that's why client see nothing. If you want your client to open a document then you need to create a response, write the content of the file in the response and specify mime type (in ContentType property). That way client's browser will figure out what program to use for opening that document (for example ContentType "application/pdf" opens with Acrobat, "application/msword" opens with Microsoft Word, etc).

See: [ASP.NET file download from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server)
And http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-summary-list/

Comment: nice example, thanks but what if I want to open url to b opened in IE not a file?

Comment: Then content disposition should be inline instead of attachment. In that case IE needs to have the plugins for correctly displaying that mime type on browser instead of calling an external application.

Comment: the problem is though I don't want to open a file but aspx page.

Comment: Add an aspx and put the code for generating response for example in the page load event. Content-Disposition is inline.