# .Net C# DocX librairy : how to serialize a DocX document?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, novacode-docx

When using the DocX librairy, i am generating the docx document on server then download it.

For that, i need to convert my document in an array of bytes.

To do that, i was previousloy saving the document as a physical file like this :

```
// Save all changes to this document.
document.SaveAs(GENERATED_DOCX_LOCATION);

return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(GENERATED_DOCX_LOCATION);
```

but i would rather not do that. Is it possible to serialize this object to download it without saving it physically ?

I already tried that :

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

With :

```
return this.ObjectToByteArray(document);
```

But obviously, DocX doesn't implement ISerializable.

**EDIT** : the code below doesn't work either

```
byte[] byteArray = null;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    document.SaveAs(stream);
    byteArray = stream.ToArray();
}
return byteArray;
```

Comment: is this a web server and internal to your organisation?

Comment: yes it's a private server, managed by a dedicated team

Comment: Take a look at this then and this should give you what you need (unless youre using MVC, which will be a different answer but I can code one up for you later if you need) but... this should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server

Comment: Actually, it's not an HTTP server. Sorry i should have been more explicit. It's a Windows Service (a WCF application) which uses a binary pipe to transfer Data. So i dont think your link can apply here (but i keep it in favorite because we are planning to migrate in SOAP in a couple of month)

Comment: ok, let me try a few things my side and i'll come back to you

Comment: next question I have is are you able to get the file into the byte array?

Comment: Yes, the first sample of code i posted do exactly that. GENERATED_DOCX_LOCATION is a private readonly string containing the location to write the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to do it via the original DocX library.

It's a shame as this library uses a MemoryStream to manupulate the datas.

To solve my problem i simply added a new public readonly property to expose the private MemoryStream variable, then i used this simple code :

Code added in the DocX project :

```
public MemoryStream DocumentMemoryStream { get { return this.memoryStream; }  }
```

Code in my main function :

```
return document.DocumentMemoryStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, replace my c:\temp... path with your document location and this will get and write the file for you from the byte array

```
void Main()
{
    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test.csv");

    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@"C:\temp\test2.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
    {
        bw.Write(bytes);
        bw.Flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your consideration but i dont want to save the file test2.csv on the disk. i found a way to get out of this by changing the DocX librairy, see my post for more details. Thank you

Comment: this was just an example of how you could do what you need to do, you dont have to save a csv file

Comment: It's not what i need to do because you start with a byte[] from a physical file, and i have a DocX to start with, in memory, not on the disk.