# Converting Byte[] to stream file asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, model-view-controller

i need to converting Byte() to stream then flush
its in asp.net application

here is my code :

```
Dim fileBytes As Byte() = Nothing

....

apiProp.BodyRequest = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(entFile)

apiProp.EndPoint = "example.com/DownloadFile"
apiProp = api.MessageInvoke(apiProp)
entResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FileResponse)(apiProp.BodyResponse)
fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(entFile.fileContent)
```

i've tried :

```
Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes)
Response.Flush()
```

and i've tried any filestream, memorystream etc. the file  ask to download, but if i download the file, the file get corrupted

i need the file converted to stream because i have to add the watermark on the image file. im using groupdocs.watermark for adding the watermark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET file download from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server)

Comment: no, because i need to process the file to adding the watermark, im using groupdocs.watermark for adding the watermark, the library need stream/file path (string) parameter but i saved my file on base64 string in my server. so i cant get the file path (or i dont understant how to get the file path if my files is converted to base64 string)

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (Stream InputStream = fl.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {
                Object o = new object();
                lock (o)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[InputStream.Length];
                    InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)InputStream.Length);
                    lock (o)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllBytes(rpath, buffer);
                        buffer = null;
                    }
                    InputStream.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Answer is C#. Question is VB.NET.